# in google sheets, automatically sum up sales between dates

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, how can I automatically sum up the sales from a particular area from the start date to end date (sample: March 3 to 10 or March 2 to 15)? Is it possible to just type the area and the dates? My file has 11 areas. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

#### SUMIFS function

The [SUMIFS function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496) returns the sum of a range depending on multiple criteria.

**Syntax:**
`SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criterion1, [criteria_range2, criterion2, ...])`

---

#### Sample Formula

[image]

```
=SUMIFS( _values, 
         _dates, ">=" & _start,
         _dates, "<=" & _end )
```

| Name | Range | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **_values** | `A2:E2` | Range of numbers to conditionally sum |
| **_dates** | `A1:E1` | Range of dates to check against criteria |
| **_start** | `H1` | Start date for criterion1: `_dates>=_start` |
| **_end** | `H2` | End date for criterion2: `_dates<=_end` |